# What's wrong with my calculation of the knot group of trefoil?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

I know standard method to compute the knot group of a trefoil $K$, regarding it as a (2,3)-torus knot. But here I find a method giving $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3-K)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, which is impossible. The question is that I cannot find out which step is wrong $\dots$

Here is my calculation:

[image]

Choose six points $\{A_1,\dots,A_6\} \subset K$ as showed in the picture. We can embed $K$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the way such that:

(1) $A_k\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\{0\}$ for all $k$;

(2) For $k$ odd, the arcs $A_kA_{k+1}$ without endpoints lie in $\{x_3< 0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$;

(3) For $k$ even, the arcs $A_kA_{k+1}$ without endpoints lie in $\{x_3>0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$.

(We agree $A_7=A_1$)

We write $U=(\mathbb{R}^3-K)\cap\{x_3\leq 0\}$, $V=(\mathbb{R}^3-K)\cap\{x_3\geq 0\}$. Then we have:

(1) $\pi_1(U)=\pi_1(V)$ is the free group generated by 3 elements, given by loops around arcs $A_kA_{k+1}$;

(2) $U\cap V=\mathbb{R}^2-\{6pts\}$, thus $\pi_1(U\cap V)$ is the free group generated by 6 elements.

(Of course we can replace $U,V$ by a little larger open sets.)

Now we apply Van Kampen's theorem.

Let $i:U\cap V\to U$, $j:U\cap V\to V$ be inclusion, then $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3-K)$ is isomorphic to the free group $\pi_1(U)*\pi_1(V)$ modulo the relations $\sim$ given by $i_*(x)=j_*(x)$ for each $x\in\pi_1(U\cap V)$.

We can write $\pi_1(U)=<a_1,a_2,a_3>$, $\pi_1(V)=<b_1,b_2,b_3>$, where $a_k$ stands for a loop rotating around $A_{2k-1}A_{2k}$ and $b_k$ corresponds to $A_{2k}A_{2k+1}$. Also write $\pi_1(U\cap V)=<c_1,\dots,c_6>$, where $c_k$ corresponds to loops rotating around $A_k$. Considering orientation, we have

$$i_*(c_1)=a_1^{\pm 1}=i_*(c_2)^{-1},\ i_*(c_3)=a_2^{\pm 1}=i_*(c_4)^{-1},\ i_*(c_5)=a_3^{\pm 1}=i_*(c_6)^{-1};$$
$$j_*(c_6)=b_3^{\pm 1}=j_*(c_1)^{-1},\ j_*(c_2)=b_1^{\pm 1}=j_*(c_3)^{-1},\ j_*(c_4)=b_2^{\pm 1}=j_*(c_5)^{-1}.$$

Then $\pi_1(U)*\pi_1(V)/\sim$ $\ \ \ $ has 6 generators, each two are identical or are inverse of each other!!!

This immediately gives a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

So where is wrong?

Comment: +1 for laying out your work. As a rule of thumb, I would double-check any place you say "of course" or "immediately" or "clearly" or anything else of the sort. More generally double-check places where you skipped details because it was obvious.

Comment: I recall enjoying this exercise in grad school. It's been 30 years, but I'm fairly sure I thought it was easier to split $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus K$ by the plane $x_1=0$ instead of $x_3=0$, but that is irrelevant. I recall having to carefully examine the picture to see what happened to the loops generating $\pi_1(U\cap V)$ when they were mapped to $\pi_(U)$ and $\pi_1(V)$. For sure the location of the base point played a big role. Where is your base point $*$? Observe that all the loops $c_i$ need to pass thru $*$.

Comment: For example, if $*$ is in the barycenter of the triangle $A_2A_4A_6$, you need to decide once and for all which way the loops $c_1,c_3,c_5$ go around $A_2,A_4,A_6$. I recall that being careful with such details paid dividends in the end.

Comment: Can you comment on the $*^\pm$ notation a bit please?

Comment: For example, if we specify that $c_1$ is the loop starting from the barycenter, heads North but goes around $A_4$ from the Eastern side, then swerves left, goes around $A_1$ clockwise, and returns back to $*$, then, indeed the image of $c_1$ in $\pi_1(U)$ (=the bottom part) just goes around the arc $A_1A_2$. But when we map that **specific** $c_1$ to $\pi_1(V)$ (=the top part) it will first go under the arc $A_4A_5$, then around the arc $A_6A_1$, and then back under the $A_4A_5$ again. Meaning that, with the simplest choices for the generators of $\pi_1(V)$, we will have...

Comment: (cont'd) that $i_*(c_1)=a_1^\pm$, but $j_*(c_1)\neq b_3$, but instead we get $j_*(c_1)$ equal to $b_2^\pm b_3^\pm b_2^\mp$ ($b_3$ conjugated by $b_2$, because the path made that detour on the other side of the $A_4A_5$ arc). There were so many choices I made in selecting the generators, that we would really need a chalkboard for this to be crystal clear. Anyway, similar things happen with other identifications. You didn't specify the generators carefully enough, and that's why you got the wrong result in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to explain my objection to OP's calculations (see the comments) visually.

Here's the trefoil. I made it a thin tube. Ignore its hollow interior that shows when I brutally crop the image.

[image]

Here's the top part with the 3 arches. This is a fattened version of OP's set $V$. I include the points with $x_3>-\epsilon$. Observe that this "universe" ends at the level of the bottom of the three arches.

[image]

Here's the bottom part with the 3 wormholes. This is a fattened version of OP's set $U$. I include the points with $x_3<\epsilon$. Observe that this "universe" ends at the level of the top of the three wormholes.

[image]

Here's a top-down view of the (fattened) middle part $U\cap V$ together with a base point (=the black dot) and a loop around the point $A_1$, i.e. a representative of the generator $c_1$ of $\pi_1(U\cap V)$.

[image]

Here's what the class of $c_1$ looks like in $\pi_1(U)$. We see that we can homotopically slide the loop along the wormhole $A_1A_2$. This shows, as the OP claimed, that $i_*(c_1)$ and $i_*(c_2)$  are either homotopic or homotopic to each others inverses depending on how we orient them. At least if we pick the obvious loop to represent $c_2$.

[image]

Here's how the class of $c_1$ looks like in the group $\pi_1(V)$. Observe that because in this space $c_1$ goes underneath the arch $A_4A_5$, we cannot simply
slide the loop along the arch $A_1A_6$. This means that $j_*(c_1)$ is not homotopic to $b_3^{\pm}$. We need to conjugate it by $b_2$ to bring it above the arch $A_4A_5$.

[image]

The OP's attempt has other similar problems in the mappings $i_*$ and $j_*$. Working all of them out is too much work - at least for now. Another way of calculating this homotopy group (a different way of using van Kampen's theorem) is given in e.g. Massey's book.

Further observe that if choose the loop $c_1$ to go around the point $A_4$ from the West side, then the OP's claim about the image $j_*(c_1)$ disappears, but
this time a similar problem appears in the bottom part, i.e. with $i_*(c_1)$.

Anyway, I'm confident that observations like this explain why OP got the wrong group to emerge, and also shows how to fix the calculations. Hope this helps in that task.

Comment: I can try to add a few other loops to the images, if it makes the point clearer. Just ask.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki! I've checked the claims about induced homomorphisms between fundamental groups and correct them. That gives the same answer as other methods. For an appropriate choice of base point and the $a_k,b_k.c_k$'s we have $$i_*(c_1)=a_1,\ i_*(c_2)=a_1^{-1},\ i_*(c_3)=a_3^{-1}a_2a_3,\ i_*(c_4)=a_2^{-1},\ i_*(c_5)=a_3,\ i_*(c_6)=a_3^{-1},\\ j_*(c_1)=b_2^{-1}b_3^{-1}b_2,\ j_*(c_2)=b_1,\ j_*(c_3)=b_1^{-1},\ j_*(c_4)=b_2,\ j_*(c_5)=b_1^{-1}b_2^{-1}b_1,\ j_*(c_6)=b_3.$$ Then we will finally get $$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3-K)\cong<a_1,a_2\ |\ a_1a_2a_1=a_2a_1a_2>,$$ which is the correct result.

Comment: Glad to hear that @WangYi. Well done! Indeed, you should get that braid relation come out (IIRC).