# Why is the fundamental group of the Hopf link abelian but a two component unlink isn't

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Title says it all basically. I'm trying to understand why the fundamental group of the hopf link (or really, the compliment of the Hopf link) is abelian. I mean, in a certain way I understand it, but on the other hand, just considering paths $a$ and $b$ where $a$ goes through one hoop and $b$ the other, I had previously convinced myself that $ab=ba$ based on the fact that the trace of their images is the same. Why is this thinking flawed? looking for general insight really

Comment: If the trace of the image was any evidence of equality, then every fundamental group would be trivial, because for any path $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$ with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=p \in X$, here is a path with the same trace which is homotopic to the constant path: $$\rho(t) = \begin{cases} \gamma(2t) & \, \text{if $0 \le t \le 1/2$} \\ \gamma(2-2t) & \, \text{if $1/2 \le t \le 1$} \end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you for this. sometimes people say such simple things and it makes so much click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Wirtinger's presentation](https://www.math.unl.edu/~mbrittenham2/classwk/872s15/hw/wirtinger.pdf), you should see that there is no relation in the fundamental group of the unlink, because there are no crossings.  So, you should always get the free group on the same number of generators as components of your unlink.

Now, for the Hopf link, again with Wirtinger's presentation.  Since there are two overarcs, you get one generator for each one, $x$ and $y$.  The relation you get around the crossings, which you can see in the image below, comes from the four strands at one of the crossings.  Follow the red strand on the left pass under $x$ and then $y$, so you get $xy$.  And that is the same as following the red dotted strand on the right, $yx$.  Hence, $xy = yx$ and the group is $\langle x,y \vert xy=yx\rangle$.  (Note, you can always exclude one crossing's relation.)

I should add an intuitive point here too.  The complement of the Hopf link in $S^3$ is really a thickened torus, $T^2 \times I$, and therefore deformation retracts to the torus.  And the torus is known to be abelian.

[image: The Hopf link with two arcs passing on either side of a crossing.]

Comment: Thanks for the link. I need to study it in detail. Anyway, Wirtinger presentation makes it completely mechanical to handle the intricacies the asker of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1885356/11619) (and yours truly) had while working out the knot group of the trefoil. All because we were armed with van Kampen alone :-)

Answer (score 3):

N. Owad already mentions how the complement of a Hopf link deformation retracts onto a torus, but I'd like to add a bit about the geometry of the complement of a split link $L$ of two unknots.  Being a split link means there is an embedded sphere in the complement separating the two components.  Since spheres are simply connected, the van Kampen theorem says that $\pi_1(S^3-L)$ is the free product of two copies of $\pi_1(B^3-U)$, where $U$ is an unknot in the ball $B^3$.  Gluing another $B^3$ to the boundary does not change the fundamental group (since the boundary $S^2$ is simply connect as is $B^3$), so $\pi_1(B^3-U)=\pi_1(S^3-U)$.  Since $S^3-U$ is a solid torus, $\pi_1(S^3-L)=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: and so the copy of $S^2$ that separates the components has one of the components entirely contained it, correct? Sorry if this an extremely trivial question haha.

Comment: Yep: in $S^3$ we have the $S^2$ and two unknots $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $S^3-S^2$ is two balls, one with $U_1$ and one with $U_2$.  If $U_i$ were in both balls, then somehow the balls would be in the same path component of $S^3-S^2$, and so $S^3-S^2$ would be connected!  (If the $S^2$ weren't just given to us and we didn't know if it was in some standard position, Alexander duality is one reason $S^3-S^2$ must have two components.  Another would be Alexander's theorem, aka the 3D Schoenflies theorem)